# Left join not returning all results

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join, aggregate-functions

I am attempting to join the two tables below to show all the columns for the incident table and just a count of the corresponding records from the tickets table with the incident_id as the same in the incidents table.

As you can see below, none of the tickets have an incident_id assigned yet. The goal of my query is to show all of the records in the incident table with a count of the ticket_ids assigned to that ticket. I thought that this would work but it's returning only one row:

```
SELECT inc.incident_id, inc.title, inc.date_opened, inc.date_closed, inc.status, inc.description, issue_type, COUNT(ticket_id) as example_count
FROM fin_incidents AS inc
LEFT OUTER JOIN fin_tickets ON inc.incident_id = fin_tickets.incident_id;
```

What query can I use to return all of the incidents and their count of tickets, even if that count is 0?

Images:

1. Incident Table
2. Tickets Table
3. Result of my query

[image: incidents table]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No GROUP BY? Your query is invalid, so don't expect it to return correct result.

Comment: @philipxy, it is? The accepted answer says the opposite.

Comment: @jarlh I said see documentation, the accepted answer is ill-phrased at the beginning, and at the end clearly agrees with me, that one can aggregate without group by. The entire table is taken as one group, with an output special case that an empty table still returns 1 row. That can reasonably be described as grouping on the empty set of columns. What the accepted answer describes in its 1st paragraph is a different problem. There are (DBMS-specific) restrictions on selecting non-grouping columns non-aggregated. See documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should not work at all -- and would fail in the more recent versions of MySQL.  The reason is that it is missing a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT inc.incident_id, inc.title, inc.date_opened, 
      inc.date_closed, inc.status, inc.description, inc.issue_type,
       COUNT(t.ticket_id) as example_count
FROM fin_incidents inc LEFT OUTER JOIN
     fin_tickets t
     ON inc.incident_id = t.incident_id
GROUP BY inc.incident_id, inc.title, inc.date_opened, 
         inc.date_closed, inc.status, inc.description, inc.issue_type
```

You have an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`.  Such a query returns exactly one row, even if the tables referred to are empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not a valid aggregation query. You have an aggregate function in the `SELECT` clause (the `COUNT()`), but no `GROUP BY` clause. When executed this with sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` disabled, MySQL gives you a single row with an overall count of tickets that are related to an incident, and any value from incident row. If that SQL mode was enabled, you would a compilation error instead.

I find that the logic you want is simpler expressed with a correlated subquery:

```
select i.*
    (select count(*) from fin_tickets t where t.incident_id = i.incident_id) as example_count
from fin_incidents i
```

This query will take advantage of an index on `fin_tickets(incident_id)` - if you have defined a foreign key (as you should have), that index is already there.